# my VOIP app is not compatible with O.S. Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I have a Toshiba VOIP app that we use for work.  Unfortunately it is not compatible with Windows 7 and the VOIP tech support confirms this.  Is there a way for me to run the app in compatibilty mode?  I would hate to have to down grade to XP

thanks for ur advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Right click on the program's shortcut or the .exe
2. Click on Properties.
3. Click on the Compatibility tab.
4. Select the `run this program in compatibility mode`
5. Select XP SP3 and try it.

It might not always work, and if you *really really* need it, you can download Windowx 7 XP Mode.